# Why my string variable recognized as empty?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an input with PHP Theme editor for Wordpress, and save it to some variable.

I want to render (echo) out the variable if is not an empty variable.

If I don't use **If**, it'll work okay (it is proof the variable not empty)

```
<div class="role"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true );?></div>
```

But when I want to echo the only variable with value, it works otherwise

```
<?php if(!empty($post_id['hcf_single_role_1'])) { ?> //if not empty
   <div class="name"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true );?></div>
<?php } else { ?> //if empty
   Variable Empty
<?php } ?>
```

if I change to `if(empty())` it'll just work otherwise, my variable recognized as an empty variable.

*edit:
I also tried `if(!empty($_POST['hcf_single_role_1']))`, but it's the same

Comment: what's the value of `$post_id['hcf_single_pic_1']` when the issue is happeing ? Is `$post_id['hcf_single_pic_1']` and `get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true )` same. Also where is `$post_id` set ?

Comment: @Bhanu sorry my bad, I edit the question, it should be `'hcf_single_role_1'`. Actually I also have other variables like `'hcf_single_pic_1'` I wrote before, all variable are string, which is not empty. But it's all not working.

Comment: You have a variable called `$post_id` that looks like it is an integer, but you are treating it like an array. Why are you mixing that array with a call to `get_post_meta`, too?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I just tried `if(!empty(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true )))` and it works. Last night I tried the same method but it didn't work, maybe just my tired eyes.

yeah I'm mixing up, cause I don't really understand. Just editing theme made by others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @ChrisHaas comment, I tried this method, and it works

```
<?php if(!empty(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true ))) { ?> //if not empty
   <div class="name"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'hcf_single_role_1', true );?></div>
<?php } else { ?> //if empty
   Variable Empty
<?php } ?>
```

The method before I messed up between array and string variables.

So I clean up with the same method I echoed with `get_post_meta()` as the if condition